# Check status of API call from different microservice after 200 response

Tags: spring-boot, rest, microservices

I have two Microservices - A & B. Microservice A has a rest endpoint which I am calling using the OpenShift Route of it from Microservice B via HTTP request. If we do an HTTP request to the OpenShift route, it has a timeout duration of 100 secs. So the HTTP request sends a response 200 while the in background the method is still running. I want to check the status of the rest endpoint method from Service B after I get the 200 response. Is there any way I can check this in SpringBoot application?

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment here that having one "microservice" directly call another one (as opposed to communicating asynchronously via a messaging plane or similar) tightly couples those two services and immediately, structurally reduces their independence.